# CSS form. Please help me with "radio" buttons

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

So... like you can see (here: http://www.ulozisko.sk/obrazky/605327/form.jpg), my problem is in "radio" buttons... i want get this buttons abreast. Can you help me?

***** Gender:

```
    <input type="radio" name="sex" />Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" />Female
```

Comment: It's happening because of your other styles.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're setting a `width` to all `input` elements. You should exlude radio buttons, such as:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but... see now http://www.ulozisko.sk/obrazky/605485/form2.jpg.. :-/

Comment: It would be much better to show your code instead of screenshots, Alex...

Comment: here is html & css: http://www.ulozisko.sk/obrazky/605492/Untitled-4.jpg

Comment: See the second answer from Nelson and think about what `label`s are and how they are used for `radio`s

Comment: I try answer from Nelson but it doesnt work for me.. i dont know.. but i really need this!

Comment: @Alexander You could remove `float`ing of the `radio` too, or you could inversly add `float` to the radio labels as well (if you use labels correctly)

Comment: In screen is my all code html&css but it didnt work ...

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<label for="male">Male</label><input type="radio" name="sex" id="male"/>
<label for="female">Female</label><input type="radio" name="sex" id="female"/>
```